# Сложение графиков изменения значений

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

У меня есть устройства в которых есть некие "слоты", в которых есть графики изменения значения этих "слотов" [image]

дальше, у меня есть, назовем подсцены, это комбинация разных устройств с разными "слотами" и разными графиками в них

и, наконец, у меня есть сцена, само собой это комбинация подсцен [image]

мне нужно сложить сцену воедино, принципы сложения графиков сцены:

1. если устройство встречается только один раз среди всех подсцен сцены, то графикb его слотов просто продлеваются на всю продолжительность сцены с крайних точек (зеленые линии) [image]
2. если устройство встречается в двух или более подсценах в одной линии, графики одинаковых слотов суммируются, и продлеваются - начало первой подсцены до начала сцены (оранжевая линия), конец до следующей сцены (зеленая линия), и конец последней до конца сцены (розовая линия)[image]
3. самый сложный вариант, когда одно устройство может встретиться в нескольких подсценах на разных линиях[image] в таком случае места пересечения подсцен (синий прямоугольник) должны сложиться по определенному типу (умножение, вычитание, максимальное значение), вот например максимальное значение [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и заполнить пустоты (приоритет зависит от линии) еще пример, допустим просто вычитание, то есть из нижней вычитаем значения верхней[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем то вопрос как это вообще сделать, я думал идти циклом по убыванию линий, складывать и продлевать графики линий, но в таком случае на итоговый график будет влиять продление, а оно должно добавляться только в итоге, если идти циклом по подсценам, то какие действия нужны, чтобы сложить точки в местах пересечения и потом продлить последнюю до следующей подсцены на этой линии? в общем пока что, как не пытался, сложить просто в тупую графики получается, а вот с определенными принципами, пока затрудняюсь, пишу это все на qt, график это QVector.
Поможет что угодно, даже примерный алгоритм или просто код в формате

Часть вопроса решена, пока что так и не понял как сделать сложение графиков, потому что оно весьма не обычное. Не понял даже как тут может помочь заметание плоскости, пересечение прямых можно найти и более простыми способами, например через QLineF.

Код который есть:

```
  scene_graphic.clear();

  QVector<SubScene*> subscenes(subscenes_);

  std::sort(subscenes.begin(), subscenes.end(), [&](SubScene *ss1, SubScene *ss2) { return ss1->GetLineIndex() > ss2->GetLineIndex(); });

  for (int i(line_count_ - 1); i >= 0; i--) {

    Q_FOREACH(SubScene *a_subscene, subscenes) {

      if (a_subscene->GetLineIndex() == i)
        Q_FOREACH(Device *a_device, a_subscene->GetDevices())
          Q_FOREACH(Slot *a_slot, *a_device->GetSlots())
            if (!a_slot->GetGraphic().isEmpty()) {

              QVector<QPoint> slot_graphic(a_slot->GetGraphic());
              QVector<QPoint> low_graphic(scene_graphic.value(a_device, QMap<a_slot, QVector<QPoint>>()).value(a_slot, QVector<QPoint>>({ QPoint(start, -1), QPoint(start + duration, -1) })));
              scene_graphic[a_device].insert(a_slot, CombineGraphics(low_graphic, slot_graphic, a_subscene->GetOverlayType()));
            }
    }
  }

/* тут еще один цикл, убирающий промежутки QPoint<time, -1> */
```

На всякий случай еще одна картинка, может так понятнее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не известно какое это устройство, какой слот, известны только точки текущего графика и добавляемого.
Получается во время прохода вышеприведенного цикла, промежутки между графиками должны быть со значениями -1, потому что значения слотов могут быть от 0 до 255, соответственно 0 принимается за существующий график, чего быть не должно, так же промежутки не должны продлеваться сразу нормальным значением, например 50, потому что там где графика нет, он должен наложиться на 0, а не на 50, поэтому после цикла сложение стоит еще один цикл, удаления точек -1 и замещения их точками со значением (он есть, код не вставил)

Comment: ¿Что тут вообще подразумевается под "график"? ¿Натурально картинка?

Comment: Да, натуральная картинка, прям как я привёл в примерах, примерно тоже самое надо получить на выходе

Comment: можно график и в QPolygon загнать, если у него есть какие то методы, которые облегчат задачу

Comment: Тогда первым шагом у вас должен быть перевод картинки в массив значений.

Comment: А, в этом плане нет, на выходе картинка, а в самих слотах устройств это записано как QVector<QPoint>

Comment: Бьем весь интервал на отрезки (по Х), координаты концов которых соответствуют крайним (по Х) точкам ваших графиков, по точкам ищем коэффициенты всех прямых в интервале, каждому отрезку должен соответствовать список комбинируемых этих самых уравнений прямых, далее , подставляя в наши прямые (заданных коэффициентами) координаты концов отрезков складываем (умножаем, вычитаем) эти прямые на заданных координатах (Х) отрезков и получаем соответствующие новые значения по Y.

Comment: Решается заметанием. События - начала и концы "устройств". События сортируются по времени, обрабатываются последовательно. Статус - все "устройства", который начались и ещё не кончились. В каждом отрезке где статус постоянен выполняется какое-то слияние устройств.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в целом найти пересечения и т.д я наверно смогу, но как описал в топике, надо продлить последнюю точку какой то подсцены, если за ней пусто, и продлить ее надо только после сложения графиков, потому что продление нижнего графика не должно влиять на наложение верхнего (если под верхним нет графика, то накладывается на 0). для этого я использую условную точку QPoint(time, -1) в начале и в конце каждого графика соответственно

Comment: Когда вы находитесь между двумя событиями в статусе есть полное описание ситуации. Например: "на первой подсцене устройство 1, на второй подсцене пусто".

Comment: можно подсказку как это примерно будет выглядеть? вот выше я добавил цикл, как он у меня есть, передается два вектора точек и тип наложения второго на первый, дальше в методе как я понял надо идти по векторам и брать по две точки каждого и искать пересечение?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил в топик предположение

Comment: я еще отредактировал вопрос, уточнил что и как должно выполняться, делал уже разные варианты, но пока никак не пойму, какой из них правильный, цикл по двум точкам двух графиков или может вообще это сделать через QPolygon.united и другие методы

Answer (score -1):

Вместо "цикл по подсценам" я бы циклом верхнего уровня объявил цикл по оси времени. Как-то так:

1. Цикл по моментам времени
2. В каждый момент определяем список сцен
3. Цикл по сценам
4. Для каждой сцены определяем список устройств в данный момент
5. Цикл по устройствам
6. Определяем тип расчёта для данного устройства: "суммирование", "продолжение" и т.д.
7. Выполняем расчёт требуемого типа.

Comment: Проблема ещё в том, что это надо делать достаточно быстро, а чтобы добраться до графика надо получить устройства подсцены -> его слоты -> График слота. Цикл по моментам времени я так понял по длительности всей сцены, сцена может быть любой длительности, хоть час, а изменение точек может и каждую миллисекунду происходить

Comment: @DaniilSavin если быстро, то анализ пересечения графиков, построение суммирующего (+,-,*...) графика надо делать в потоке, а результат уже отображаться в гуи отдельно. Вам надо отделить данные от отображения. В общем случае построение суммарного графика при наложении непростая задача (даже если графики линейные)

Comment: это все уже происходит в потоке, само собой

Comment: Цикл не по всем моментам, а только там где "устройства" начинаются или заканчиваются. Интервалы между ними обрабатываются целиком.